# Is it possible to supply an Object's data to Reporting Services via its' web service for it to use to generate reports

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I want to be able to supply the data for Reporting Services to use to generate a report (for example an XML Serialized object, but it doesn't have to be). Is this possible? If so, how would I do that?

Comment: You can consume SSIS objects, if that's any help

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345250(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind all sorts of things to the datasource property of the [report viewer control](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/).

The server always uses the data source that is defined in the report itself. So, if you have to use the report server, you have to funnel any dynamic data through the database.

Answer (score 1):

Just recently implemented a solution where we pulled-down data from a database via a WCF service, mapped it to a complex type (class with several properties, three of which were List), and used that as an object data source to display a report in a ReportViewer control on the client. This did not require Reporting Services at all.

Comment: Wow, sounds impressive. Does that mean that the report itself (.rdl) is embedded in the client? How exactly do you do that?

Comment: Yes, the report is included in the client project as an embedded resource and referenced in the report viewer control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "XML" Data Provider with your data embedded into a DataSource query or queries from a Web Service, using an <strike>XPath</strike>Element path expression to define and extract your DataSet.

There is some documentation on MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365158.aspx, but it's not comprehensive.

Somebody should post an example.